# Azure Table Storage Query Performance

Tags: azure, query-performance, azure-table-storage

Would there be much difference in the performance, of a Table Storage query, if you knew the exact Partition Key and RowKey?

We use a datetime for the RowKey and to get the latest entry we retrieve everything for a day and then sort it in code.

```
PartitionKey eq '123456' and RowKey ge '20170713000000000' and RowKey le '20170714000000000'
```

Would this retrieve record from table storage quicker?

```
PartitionKey eq '123456' and RowKey eq '20170713101000000'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **PartitionKey eq '123456' and RowKey eq '20170713101000000'**

This query will definitely be faster than

> **PartitionKey eq '123456' and RowKey ge '20170713000000000' and RowKey
>   le '20170714000000000'**

The first query makes use of all the available indexes (`PartitionKey` and `RowKey`) and is a point query.

The second query is also efficient (though not as much as the 1st one) because it is only searching in a single partition however it is doing what is known as `Partition Scan`. This query will go to the desired partition and then perform a search for matching `RowKey` values. As the number of entities in a partition grow, you will notice a degradation in performance in the 2nd query.